# Sort backbone collection without rerender each view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to sort and re-nder my model in right place after change of status property.

**ItemsView**

```
render: function(){
  for(var i=0; i < this.collection.length; i++){
    this.renderItem(this.collection.models[i]); 
  }
  return this;

},
renderItem: function( model ){
  // here I'm creating new ItemView for every model in collection
  var itemView = new ItemView({ model: model }); 
  itemView.render();
  jBone(this.el).append(itemView.el);
}
```

**ItemView**

```
initialize: function () {
  _.bindAll(this, 'updateOrderStatus');
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:status', this.updateOrderStatus);
},    
render: function () {
  var model = this.model.toJSON();
  this.el.innerHTML += '<p>'+model.title+'</p><div>'+model.status+'</div>';
  return this;
},
updateOrderStatus: function(newstuff){
  // Here I wanna to set directly new status of model into element, basically it is 
  // what I want to do but views are not sorted. Is possible to sort views without rerender each view in collection in new order?
  this.el.firstChild.setAttribute("class",this.model.get("status"));
  // Also I can remove view via this.remove() 
  // but is possible to render new one in right place in the list ?
},
```

**ItemsCollection**

```
comparator: function(item) {
  return -item.get('status');
},
initialize: function () {
  this.bind('change:status', function( model, prop ){
      model.collection.sort();
      // sort function is fired after status has changed
      // model has new position in collection
  });
}
```

I hope there is some way how to change order of views without reset or re-render whole collection.
App is published in [Github](https://github.com/makromat/BackboneAPP)
Thanks for any opinion.

Comment: We can remove the specific view and append it to right place in `DOM`. Can you share a simple demo that we can play with..?

Comment: @TJ Thanks for your interest, I uploaded code to github. Please take a look https://github.com/makromat/BackboneAPP. I will be very grateful if you help me.

Comment: oh I did it thanks :D